# Vacation travel to Canada with a company-owned laptop

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, electronic-items

I have an upcoming vacation for a couple of days in Canada (as a leg of a longer trip in the US [I am a US citizen]). I'd like to bring my company-owned laptop so I can check my email while I'm there. My company has provided me with a letter for customs with a bunch of legalese explaining that it's OK for me to bring the laptop into the country.

Do I need to notify the customs officials that I have the laptop, or is the letter only to be presented if it comes up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No you do not have to do anything unless asked (and that is unlikely). A sizeable fraction of people traveling will have notebook computers with them, owned by themselves or their companies. Nobody typically pays much attention to a machine that's obviously not brand new in the box.

However, keep in mind that officials on both sides of the border can ask for passwords and sift through any of your electronic devices if they feel like it.

Comment: Officials on the US side of the border can *ask* a US citizen for their password but can’t do anything if you say “no”.

Comment: @JonathanReez: They might not be able to *require* that you reveal your password, but they have nearly unlimited power to make your life more difficult in other ways.

Comment: On the Canadian side "Failure to grant access to your digital device may result in the detention of that device under section 101 of the Customs Act, or seizure of the device under subsection 140 (1) of the Immigration and Refugee Protection Act". Also, you can be charged with obstructing border officials and fined. On the US side, the CBP will also seize ("detain") your device for an indeterminate time and they can hold you, hard to say how long, courts found a few hours constitutional so far.

Comment: @JonathanReez they can. They can confiscate the device under "suspicion of being related to a criminal organisation or terrorism" or something like that until they either manage to break in or you hand over your credentials. And they can basically do the same to you plus "obstruction of an official investigation" which is a federal crime. TSA and DHS have near unlimited powers like that, which is why many non-US companies now won't allow their employees to take ANY company owned devices through US customs.

Comment: @jwenting Exactly that. Were I work nobody travels to the USA with a company laptop or phone. The US based offices have loaner equipment available for visitors from outside USA. Due to industry regulations and GDPR compliance our employees are not allowed to give border-control access to the equipment and can potentially be confronted with a lot of hassle, detention or being refused entry. We just don't want to expose them to that.

Comment: In addition to the US possibility of holding the device for an indeterminate amount of time, there's also the possibility that they can convince a judge to give them a warrant or to order you to provide a password. In the second case, you will be liable for penalties for contempt of court if you do not comply. If the officers are just trying to make your life hard, they won't do this, but if they truly suspect you of a crime, they will. I presume that similar measures can be taken by Canada. If the information is very sensitive, the risks associated with misplaced suspicion may be unwarranted.

Comment: @jwenting not just non-US companies.  My previous US employer gave burner laptops to people going to Canada for business.  They had no company data going north, everything needed was pulled down over VPN on arrival.  Matching paranoia going south would include something to clear the browser cache and nuke any local files; but I don't know if that was done or not.

Comment: @JonathanReez your comment and the following replies are a nice example of US freedom in theory vs US freedom in practice

Comment: @phoog it's complicated, see [this question on Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/can-a-us-citizen-be-required-to-provide-the-authentication-key-for-encrypted-dat).